# Connecting Arduino Ethernet Shield and reading data issue PROCESSING

Tags: udp, arduino, processing, ethernet

i am new to this forum and the whole thing with Processing.
I have a specific question to ask and thanks a lot for your time and thoughts!

How can i connect my Arduino with Ethernet Shield, getting temperature values from a sensor so they can be seen to a processing script?
In a straight Arduino script, one gets the value, connects from the ethernet shield to a server and does what one likes. I have accomplished that.

In my case i want Arduino to just run the script of reading an analog input value from the sensor.
Is it possible?

I have made the serial connection work and read the values alright through the usb, but with ethernet shield? How can i get the value that arduino reads **WITHOUT USB/Serial connection?**

ps. i am using WAMP server etc, Windows 7

I am trying the UDP connection script example for both arduino and processing from http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/UDPSendReceiveString, but

1)i ain't sure if that's what i need,

2)i have excluded from firewall ports 6000, 8888 for my tests and have put the IP address of my Arduino at the Arduino script and "localhost" at the Processing script

THE CODE COPIED FOR BETTER USE HERE

```
/*
  UDPSendReceive.pde:
 This sketch receives UDP message strings, prints them to the serial port
 and sends an "acknowledge" string back to the sender

 A Processing sketch is included at the end of file that can be used to send
 and received messages for testing with a computer.

 created 21 Aug 2010
 by Michael Margolis

 This code is in the public domain.
 */


#include <SPI.h>         // needed for Arduino versions later than 0018
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <EthernetUdp.h>         // UDP library from: bjoern@cs.stanford.edu 12/30/2008


// Enter a MAC address and IP address for your controller below.
// The IP address will be dependent on your local network:
byte mac[] = {  
  0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 1, 177);

unsigned int localPort = 8888;      // local port to listen on

// buffers for receiving and sending data
char packetBuffer[UDP_TX_PACKET_MAX_SIZE]; //buffer to hold incoming packet,
char  ReplyBuffer[] = "acknowledged";       // a string to send back

// An EthernetUDP instance to let us send and receive packets over UDP
EthernetUDP Udp;

void setup() {
  // start the Ethernet and UDP:
  Ethernet.begin(mac,ip);
  Udp.begin(localPort);

  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // if there's data available, read a packet
  int packetSize = Udp.parsePacket();
  if(packetSize)
  {
    Serial.print("Received packet of size ");
    Serial.println(packetSize);
    Serial.print("From ");
    IPAddress remote = Udp.remoteIP();
    for (int i =0; i < 4; i++)
    {
      Serial.print(remote[i], DEC);
      if (i < 3)
      {
        Serial.print(".");
      }
    }
    Serial.print(", port ");
    Serial.println(Udp.remotePort());

    // read the packet into packetBufffer
    Udp.read(packetBuffer,UDP_TX_PACKET_MAX_SIZE);
    Serial.println("Contents:");
    Serial.println(packetBuffer);

    // send a reply, to the IP address and port that sent us the packet we received
    Udp.beginPacket(Udp.remoteIP(), Udp.remotePort());
    Udp.write(ReplyBuffer);
    Udp.endPacket();
  }
  delay(10);
}


/*
  Processing sketch to run with this example
 =====================================================

 // Processing UDP example to send and receive string data from Arduino
 // press any key to send the "Hello Arduino" message
 */

 import hypermedia.net.*;

 UDP udp;  // define the UDP object


 void setup() {
 udp = new UDP( this, 6000 );  // create a new datagram connection on port 6000
 //udp.log( true );         // <-- printout the connection activity
 udp.listen( true );           // and wait for incoming message  
 }

 void draw()
 {
 }

 void keyPressed() {
 String ip       = "192.168.1.177"; // the remote IP address
 int port        = 8888;        // the destination port

 udp.send("Hello World", ip, port );   // the message to send

 }

 void receive( byte[] data ) {          // <-- default handler
 //void receive( byte[] data, String ip, int port ) {   // <-- extended handler

 for(int i=0; i < data.length; i++)
 print(char(data[i]));  
 println();  
 }
```

Comment: This isn't directly answering your question, but can you please prototype the communication WITH a USB/Serial connection first to make sure you can send and recieve/organize the information in Processing first ? There is a built in Arduino library which should help you...

Comment: Thank you for the reply jesses,
but as i have already stated, serial connection is just fine, everything works as expected.
ps. can you plz specify what you mean by prototype?

Answer (score 1):

Read those values into a file and use that file to send data to processing. http://py.processing.org/reference/createReader.html

Answer (score 0):

Great scheme. Only one problem. It works perfectly on my system. I loaded my Arudino Uno R3 with your Arduino sketch and loaded the Processing sketch as well. Worked like a charm, first try. Didn't change anything on my Arduino, Windows system, Processing (2.0.3), network, etc.

Could be you have a Arduino board problem (unlikely) or an Ethernet shield problem (sadly, more likely). You could have a network problem (even more likely).

Try Wireshark. You will really just be guessing until you take a look at the Wireshark output. Note that Wireshark has filters. You will need them. Filter out all of the non-UDP traffic.